# View dissapears when Modal is Opened

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview, modal-dialog

I have basic storyboard that contains a subview with some labels to display information. This view is hidden off screen and pops up and down when a user has music playing/paused. This view starts off screen at the bottom and animates accordingly.

Another button on the screen opens a modal window. When this modal is opened, the subview with labels will return to its initial state off screen. I have notification center in my main View Controller successfully detecting when this modal is closed but its calling the appropriate functions to show the subview again if music is playing. However the view will not animate for some reason, even if I set the values directly without animation. Yet after pressing pause/play it will appear again as its supposed to.

I assume I have to use some appropriate callback so the animation is called only after the view is ready to redraw or something? Find below the methods that open my modal and the method called when it is closed.

```
// open modal from a .xib
- (IBAction)openModal:(id)sender {
    ifmSettingsViewController* svc = [[ifmSettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Settings" bundle:nil];
    [svc setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
    [svc setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
        selector:@selector(didDismissSecondViewController)
        name:@"SecondViewControllerDismissed"
        object:nil];
    [self presentViewController:svc animated:TRUE completion:nil];
}
// called when modal window dismissed
-(void)didDismissSecondViewController {
    NSLog(@"Dismissed SecondViewController");
    [self viewDidAppear:TRUE];
    // calculate appropriate distance from screen bottom
    float yer = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height - 101.0;
    self.infoview.center = yer;
}
```

Within the modal, it closes itself as follows:

```
- (IBAction)backHit:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:TRUE completion:^{
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"SecondViewControllerDismissed"
            object:nil
            userInfo:nil
        ];
        return;
    }];
}
```